# ASP: Filtering and Parsing many XML records from SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I apologize if this question has been asked, but I have not yet found a solution here that works for me. I am new to working with XML.

I have an SQL Server table (called "Answers") that contains a column of type XML (called "XmlColumn"). The rows look something like this (each line being a distinct record).

```
<value type="option" />
<value type="numeric" value="250" />
<value type="string" value="Sample Text" />
<value type="numeric" value="" />
```

My question is, from my ASP project, how can I:

1. Select all records of type="numeric"
2. Parse all "value"s as int

Currently, I have something that works, but I'm not convinced it's an ideal solution:

```
     var allAnswers = MyModel.Context.Answers.Select(a => a.XmlColumn);
     List<int> allNumericAnswers = new List<int>();
     foreach (var answer in allAnswers)
     {
        string type = (string)XElement.Parse(answer).Attribute("type");
        string value = (string)XElement.Parse(answer).Attribute("value");
        if (type == "numeric")
        {
           int numericVal;
           bool res = int.TryParse(value, numericVal);
           if (res)
           {
              allNumericAnswers.Add(numericVal);
           }
        }
     }
     //Now allNumericAnswers is holding all integer values of type "numeric"
     //and I can manipulate them as necessary.
```

My goal is to perform queries such as "Find the average of all numeric values" or "Select all numeric values > 50", etc. So far, all searches have lead me to solutions for traversing, filtering, parsing, etc within a *single* XML document, however I want to parse and manipulate thousands of these records at a time, and store them in something like an array for further calculations.

Is there a more elegant solution to what I'm doing above?

Comment: Is it required that you do it in your ASP project as opposed to doing it in a stored procedure?

Comment: @ClintB Not necessarily, although I've been working in ASP because that's what I'm more comfortable in. But if a stored procedure is the better solution, I'll look into it. Can you link to a resource I can use to get started?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing this in SQL would be much more efficient.  You wouldn't have to send the entire table contents over the wire and SQL is optimized to handle this type of data interrogation.

Here is a way to get the values where (type="numeric" and value != "") and return the values as an integer.

```
select convert(int, XmlColumn.value('(/value[@type="numeric" and @value!=""]/@value)[1]', 'varchar(20)')) as NumericValue
from Answers
where XmlColumn.value('(/value[@type="numeric" and @value!=""]/@value)[1]', 'varchar(20)') is not null
```

Throw an avg on that to get the average

```
select avg(convert(int, XmlColumn.value('(/value[@type="numeric" and @value!=""]/@value)[1]', 'varchar(20)'))) as NumericValue
from Answers
where XmlColumn.value('(/value[@type="numeric" and @value!=""]/@value)[1]', 'varchar(20)') is not null
```

Make it a sub-query to get all the ones that have a value > 50

```
select NumericValue from 
(
    select convert(int, XmlColumn.value('(/value[@type="numeric" and @value!=""]/@value)[1]', 'varchar(20)')) as NumericValue
    from Answers
    where XmlColumn.value('(/value[@type="numeric" and @value!=""]/@value)[1]', 'varchar(20)') is not null 
) a
where NumericValue > 50
```

Comment: Fantastic, many thanks. I did a quick test, and this approach is indeed faster. More importantly the XML data doesn't have to be sent over the network & loaded into memory for a simple conversion.